# React native dropdown picker not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have used React native dropdown picker in order to show a list of items but the picker seems to be not responding on any clicks

below is the complete code that I have written:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent from './components/HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent';
import {API} from '../../api';
import HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent from './components/HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent';
import HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent';
import HomeTabExpertCardComponent from './components/HomeTabExpertCardComponent';
import HomeTabPremiumCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPremiumCardComponent';
import HomeTabPrimeCardComponent from './components/HomeTabPrimeCardComponent';
import HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent from './components/HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent';

export default function HomeTabScreen(props) {
  console.log(
    ' ~ file: HomeTabScreen.js ~ line 12 ~ HomeTabScreen ~ props',
    props,
  );
  const {navigation} = props;
  const mHomeTabResponse = null;
  const [mainResponse, setMainResponse] = useState([]);
  const [mAssessmentList, setAssessmentList] = useState([]);
  const [mWeekWiseMediaList, setWeekWiseMedialist] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userObject, setUserObject] = useState(null);
  const [childId, setChild] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userObject) {
      getHomeTabMainAPI();
    } else {
      getData();
    }
  }, [userObject]);

  const getData = () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = AsyncStorage.getItem('user_object').then(
        (result) =>
          // console.log('result', JSON.parse(result)),
          setUserObject(JSON.parse(result).children),

        // console.log('userssss', userObject),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
  const getHomeTabMainAPI = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await API.get(
        `some url`,
      );
      console.log('res', response);

      setAssessmentList(response.data.content.assessments.data);
      setWeekWiseMedialist(response.data.content.media_cards.data);
      setTitle(response.data.content.assessments.title);
      setText(response.data.content.assessments.text);

      setMainResponse(response.data.content.assessments.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const logoutHandler = () => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem('user_object').then(navigation.navigate('login'));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    console.log('Done.');
  };
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FE017E" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {console.log('object', userObject)}
      {userObject &&
        userObject != '' &&
        userObject != null &&
        userObject != undefined &&
        userObject.length > 1 && (
          <DropDownPicker
            items={userObject.map((item) => {
              return {
                label: item.name,
                value: item.id,
              };
            })}
            containerStyle={{height: 40}}
          />
        )}

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          marginLeft: '80%',
        }}
        onPress={() => logoutHandler()}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000'}}>
          Log out
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={{paddingBottom: 58}}>
        {/* {console.log('view mWeekWiseMediaList - ' + mWeekWiseMediaList)} */}
        {mWeekWiseMediaList !== null && mWeekWiseMediaList.length > 0 ? (
          <HomeTabWeekWiseImagesCardComponent data={mWeekWiseMediaList} />
        ) : (
          <Text></Text>
        )}
        <HomeTabOverAllDevelopmentCardComponent />
        <HomeTabPremiumCardComponent />
        {/* {mAssessmentList &&
          mAssessmentList != '' &&
          mAssessmentList != null &&
          mAssessmentList.length > 1 &&
          userObject != null &&
          userObject != '' &&
          userObject != undefined &&
          userObject[0] &&
          userObject[0] != null &&
          userObject[0] != undefined &&
          userObject[0] != '' && (
            <HomeTabAssessmentCardComponent
              data={mAssessmentList}
              title={title}
              text={text}
              navigation={props}
              children={userObject.children[0].id}
              childrenObject={userObject.children[0]}
            />
          )} */}

        <HomeTabPrimeCardComponent />
        <HomeTabPhysicalGrowthCardComponent />
        <HomeTabExpertCardComponent />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

If anyone could let mw know where am going wrong or why is my dropdown not responding it would be a great help.
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bracket in return

```
          return ({
            label: item.name,
            value: item.id,
          });
```

Try pasting this code

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. its running in infinite loop because userObject is in dependency array. Please remove it from useEffect dependency array, keep it empty.

also, if getHomeTabMainAPI() and getData() are independent of each other. you do not need if else block. let me know if this work.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getHomeTabMainAPI();
  }, []);
```